# How do I keep an empty list sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using sortable on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aJTe5/

It's a team organization system.  The issue I'm having is that if you drag all players on Team 3 to other teams, you can't re-add players to team 3.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Just a dirty thought; what if you let the team name itself be a li to, but never save them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set properties to `ul` tags, when there is no element it becomes width-less and height-less:

```
ul {
   min-width: 128px;
   min-height: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aJTe5/2/